# getting a dictionary of class variables and values

Tags: python, class, dictionary, class-variables

I am working on a method to return all the class variables as keys and values as values of a dictionary , for instance i have:

first.py

```
class A:
    a = 3
    b = 5
    c = 6
```

Then in the second.py i should be able to call maybe a method or something that will return a dictionary like this

```
import first

dict = first.return_class_variables()
dict
```

then dict will be something like this:

```
{'a' : 3, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 6}
```

This is just a scenario to explain the idea, of course i don't expect it to be that easy, but i will love if there are ideas on how to handle this problem just like **dict** can be used to set a class variables values by passing to it a dictionary with the variable, value combination as key, value.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, what do you mean by 'class variables'?

Comment: Class attributes, the answers below was what i was looking for.:)

Comment: k, just keep in mind that will also include methods of the class and will not give you any attributes defined in a parent class.

Comment: Yes, the class i am working on contains only attributes no methods, thank you i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to filter out functions and built-in class attributes.

```
>>> class A:
...     a = 3
...     b = 5
...     c = 6
... 
>>> {key:value for key, value in A.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('__') and not callable(key)}
{'a': 3, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}
```

Comment: Minor correction: I think that should be ...`and not callable(value)}`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
  class A(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.a = 3
          self.b = 5
          self.c = 6

  def return_class_variables(A):
      return(A.__dict__)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      a = A()
      print(return_class_variables(a))
```

which gives

```
{'a': 3, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}
```

Comment: I would recommend renaming the class...for added clarity with respect to the return_class_variables() method.

Comment: You're setting and returning instance variables, not the class variable. Class variables are not defined in `__init__()` but just after the `class` statement. Class variables are common to all instances, whereas instance variables belong to the instance only (the Class object can't access instance variables, although the opposite is possible).

Answer (score 3):

afkfurions highly upvoted and accepted answer is **incomplete and contains a mistake** that will be visible for less trivial classes. It will include things like classmethods and staticmethods in the result which is probably unwanted. Here is a version that will work (also including the fix suggested by realgeek):

```py
class B:
    a = 3
    b = 2
    
    @classmethod
    def fn(cls):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

    def method(self):
        pass

d = {
    key:value for key, value in B.__dict__.items() 
    if not key.startswith('__') 
    and not callable(value) 
    and not callable(getattr(value, "__get__", None)) # <- important
}
print(d) # {'a': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Explanation: A class-attribute may be a [get-set-descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). In this case, accessing the value in the classes `__dict__` will yield the object implementing the descriptor-protocol and not the value represented by that object.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension on `A.__dict__` and filter out keys that start and end with `__`:

```
>>> class A:
        a = 3
        b = 5
        c = 6
...     
>>> {k:v for k, v in A.__dict__.items() if not (k.startswith('__')
                                                             and k.endswith('__'))}
{'a': 3, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution and most pythonic is to use `var(class_object)` or `var(self)` (if trying to use inside class).

This although do avoids dictionary pairs where the key is another object and not a default python type.

```py
>>> class TheClass():
>>>    def __init__(self):
>>>        self.a = 2
>>>        self.b = 1
>>>        print(vars(self))
>>> class_object= TheClass()
{'a'=2, 'b'=1}
```

Or outside class

```py
>>> vars(class_object)
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__dict__` to get the list of a class variables. For example, if you have a class like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {key: value for key, value in self.__dict__.items()}
```

You can get the list of variables this way:

```
some_class = SomeClass(1,2,3)
some_class.to_dict()
```

And the output will be:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the built-in vars method of python.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vars-function-python/#

From the website:

`vars(object)`

> The method returns the **dict** attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object if the same has a **dict** attribute. If the object fails to match the attribute, it raises a TypeError exception. Objects such as modules and instances have an updatable **dict** attribute however, other objects may have written restrictions on their **dict** attributes. vars() acts like locals() method when an empty argument is passed which implies that the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

From your example:

- Create an object instance (that has initialised values for each of the properties

```
a_obj = A()
```

- Use the vars function

```
vars(a_obj)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 3, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}
```