# How to properly share variable references between classes

Tags: python, reference, keyword-argument

Say you have some classes (Foo, Bar) that define a few variables (mixture of mutable and immutable objects). Now, there's another class FooBar that can change the values of Foo and Bar, and for that they need to share their references appropriately. So I thought I could come up with something like the following:

```
def var_dict(object):
    return {key:value for key, value in object.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('__') and not callable(key)}

# Foo class
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.text = None
        self.id = 0

    def read(self):
        input = FooBar(**var_dict())

# Bar class
class Bar:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.id = None
        self.l = list()

    def read(self):
        input = FooBar(**var_dict())


class FooBar:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.text = kwargs.get("text",None)
        self.id = kwargs.get("id",None)
        self.l = kwargs.get("l",None)

    def process(self):

        if self.text:
            print("text", self.text)
            self.text = "text processed"
        if self.id:
            print("id", self.id)
        if self.l:
            # do further processing
            self.l += ['processed']
```

The `var_dict` function was obtained [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322244/getting-a-dictionary-of-class-variables-and-values). Now when I try the code as follows:

```
f = Foo()
f.text = "foo"
f.id = 1

b = Bar()
b.id = 2
b.l = [1,2,3]

fb1 = FooBar(**var_dict(f))
fb1.process()
print(f.text)
print(f.id)

fb2 = FooBar(**var_dict(b))
fb2.process()
print(b.id)
print(b.l)
```

it prints:

```
text foo
id 1
foo
1
id 2
2
[1, 2, 3, 'processed']
```

and as expected only the mutable variables are changed in the original classes. So my question is then: is there a way to make sure whenever you change a reference in FooBar, this also changes the variable in the original Foo and Bar classes irrespective of whether the variable is mutable or immutable? Also, is the `**kwargs` shown above the most Pythonic way to pass the references between classes?

Comment: As you seem to know in which way (and what) you want to change in `Foo` and `Bar` why don't you simply pass their references to the constructor of `FooBar` and then you change e.g. the text like `self.whatever.text = ...`. You can enclose this in a `try` block and `except` an `AttributeError`. What is your actual goal here? Only changing randomly the attributes of some classes? I guess this will be part of some bigger logical structure. I don't really see why you need this workaround with `var_dict` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: The reason is that there may be many classes like `Foo` and `Bar`, and also many classes like `FooBar`. So the point is to do something generic, so some `FooBar_n` class would change the variables in some `Foo_n` class _only_ if the latter contains the variables that the former can actually modify.

Comment: Why is `FooBar` even a separate class, rather than a method defined on the class whose instance you want to modify? `f = Foo(); f.process()`.

Comment: That's the structure of the code I'm writing and that can't change. To give you some insight, I would like to make the use of classes like `FooBar` completely independent so they can take any class (to factor code), even if those `Foo` and `Bar` classes were not written in Python.

Comment: @aaragon: That's why I suggested to enclose it in a `try` block. In `FooBar.process` you try to modify some variables of e.g. `Foo` (I'd say those are the ones which the former can actual (try to) modify) and the `try` statement ensures you only (try to) modify those which the latter actually contains. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This still doesn't solve the fundamental problem that I pointed out in the post: the fact that you can modify only mutable objects. Look at the printout at the end of my post.

Comment: No, you can modify members of **any** type if you have the reference to the instance of a class. Suppose you have a class `f = Foo()` and a class fb = `FooBar(f)`. Then you can do anything in `fb` with `f`. If you do (within a method of `FooBar`) `instance.string = 'new string'` this will create a new `str` object and assign its reference to the variable `string` of `instance`. Therefore you can also 'modify' immutable objects (ok, of course you cannot modify them as they are *immutable* but you can create new, 'modified' objects and assign them to the old variable which has the same effect).